# Eclipse CDT (Atollic 8.1 Eclipse Neon.1a) - Clean Command

Tags: eclipse

I use Atollic 8.1 which is build up upon Eclipses Neon 1a release on Windows 10.

The Clean command is by default "rm -rf" in the .cproject. When executed, the clean command removes all *.o and *.d objects im Debug/Release but not *.su files.

When comparing to newer Eclipse releases, the clean command actually is able to delete the entire Debug / Release folder (Build Outputs).

I tried to do the same by manually editing the clean command in .cproject by writing "rm -rf Debug Release", so when executed, Eclipse does something like this in the background:

"rm -rf Debug Release *.o *.d" but currently it still ignores Debug and Release.

---

So why are they not deleted? Then i replaced "rm -rf" with "pwd" and noticed that it is executing from inside the Debug folder.

So my .cproject executes now "rm -rf ../Debug ../Release" which is working ... kinda...

The Debug folder is completely empty, which is my goal. But:
I get the error:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Atollic\TrueSTUDIO for ARM 8.1.0\Tools\rm.exe: cannot remove directory `../Debug': Permission denied

I believe that since it executes the actual "rm -rf ../Debug" command but since it is executing from inside the Debug folder, it recreates it and issues the warning.

Is there a better way around this?

Comment: Why do you use such an old Eclipse version if a newer version solves the problem, as you say yourself?

Comment: cause i use Atollic with is a licenced product and does not come with an update.